# How to limit the column length while using collection of primitive type?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "db_foo")
public List<String> foo;
```

i want to add limitation on foo elements length (something like `@Column(length=x)`). Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `@Column(length=x)`? As far as I understand, it should work in this case as well.

Comment: No, i haven't. Doesn't seem obvious. Thank you :)