# How to add constraint to collection items

Tags: java, hibernate, bean-validation

I have an entity with collection of strings. I would like to add a constrains that will check if all items in the collection have size less then 255.

Let's say I have an entity `Area` with a collection of `references`. I would like to be sure that all references are shorter then 255 characters. Do you know how can I achieve it.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AREA")
public class Area  Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4756123949793458708L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "AREA_REFERENCES", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "AREA_ID"))
    @Column(name = "REFERENCE", nullable = false)
    @Size(max = 255) // THIS ANNOTATION SEEMS TO NOT WORK
    private Set<String> references = new HashSet<>();

    ....
```

Comment: Check the spring validator:  https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Comment: Another way of achieving it is to wrap the String itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Annotating like this

```
@Size(max = 255)
private Set<String> references;
```

means the `Set<String>` is allowed to contain a maximum of 255 strings.
Of course this is not what you want.

Instead, you want each string to have a maximum of 255 characters:
You can achieve it by annotating the type parameter within `< >` like this:

```
private Set<@Size(max = 255) String> references;
```

For that you will need quite new versions of Hibernate Validator (6.0.x)
and Bean Validation (2.0.1).

See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49965678/how-to-validate-a-listbigdecimal-with-decimalmin-and-decimalmax/49966128#49966128) for a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to [how-to-limit-the-column-length-while-using-collection-of-primitive-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426279/how-to-limit-the-column-length-while-using-collection-of-primitive-type) you could set the size constraint to the Column annotation.

Comment: Not sure if the thread below is valid but you should check it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875149/what-does-the-length-attribute-do-when-set-on-the-column-jpa-annontation#answer-25803065

Answer (score 0):

For validation, you could add a like `@Size(max=allowed_length)` constraint from the Bean Validation API (JSR 303).

Hibernate uses Bean Validation constraints to generate an accurate database schema.
for example :

`@Size.max` leads to a `varchar(max)` definition for `Strings` and 
`@Min, @Max` lead to column checks (like value <= max)

Comment: How is this post answering the OP question?